# Room: How to get albums and all songs with single DAO method

Tags: android, android-room, dao

Asuming a database schema with Artist, Album, and Song, where an Artist can have many Albums and an Album can have many songs, is there a way to define a DAO method that would get me a list of all Albums and all Songs of each Album?

I know I can get Song and Album with something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Song s JOIN Album a ON s.albumId = a.id")
List<SongAndAlbum> loadSongAndAlbum();
```

but I have no idea how to define a query that would provide a list of all Albums and all Songs of seach Album.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have such a scheme:

```
@Entity
public class Artist {
    @PrimaryKey public long Id;
    public String name;
}

@Entity
public class Album {
    @PrimaryKey public long Id;
    public String name;
    public int artistId;
}
@Entity
public class Song {
    @PrimaryKey public long Id;
    public String name;
    public int albumId;
}
```

To get List with Albums with each album holding List of songs you can use [Room's Relations](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#java):

```
public class AlbumWithSongs {
    @Embedded public Album album;
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "id",
         entityColumn = "albumId"
    )
    public List<Song> songs;
}
```

Your dao method should be:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Album")
List<AlbumWithSongs> loadAlbumWithSongs();
```

If in addition to that you want to get List with Artists with each artist holding list of albums you should add one more class:

```
public class ArtistWithAlbums {
    @Embedded public Artist artist;
    @Relation(
         entity = Album.class,
         parentColumn = "id",
         entityColumn = "artistId"
    )
    public List<AlbumWithSongs> albums;
}
```

Your dao method for that should be:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Artist")
List<ArtistWithAlbums> loadArtistWithAlbums();
```